# Print array[1] to array[n]

Tags: php, html

I have a post like a blog and i want to change the color of the first word. For example i have  title like `Test Post` and i want to change the color of `Test` only without change the color of `Post`.

I have a code:

```
 <?php
   $title = get_the_title();
   $title_array = explode(' ', $title);
 ?>
 <h2>
   <span class="yellow">
     <?php echo $title_array[0] ?>
   </span>
     <?php echo $title_array[1] ?>
 </h2>
```

HTML generated by code:

```
<h2><strong><a href="http://credexpert/test-post/" title="Permalink to test post raam naam" rel="bookmark"><span class="yellow"> test</span> Array</a></strong></h2>
```

code is working fine, But the problem comes when title is long, Suppose the title would be `Test Post for Content Box`

Is there any way to print the remaining arrays with short code from `array[1] to array[n]`.

Comment: `var_dump($title_array)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you forgot to put semicolon `;` at end of `echo`s.

You could use

```
$title_array = explode(' ', $title,2);
```

This will cause that you get two strings: first would be the first word, and the other - the rest.

Refer to [explode in manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: In those cases semicolon could be ommited without any warning, but yes he should rather use it always.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by  loop

1, either by [**`for`**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop

```
for($a = 0; $a<count($array);$a++)
{
 echo $title_array[$a] ;

}
```

2, or by [**`foreach`**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop like

```
foreeach($title_array as $item){
   echo $item;
}
```

3, or by [**`while`**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) loop

```
$a= 0;
while($a<count($title_array)){
  echo $title_array[$a] ;
  $a++;
}
```

4, or by recursion

whoa whoa i think above three approaches are  enough

and as @Voitcus telling you should use semicolon at the end of line its good practice and also it doesnot mean that we should use it after loop(except in some condition )   or if

Comment: Array should start with 0 know. Then $a should be 0

Comment: @EdwinAlex damn on me its  just an bad bad typo and thanyou